# Overloading function signatures haskell

Tags: haskell, type-signature

I get the following error message when I compile:

> Duplicate type signature:
>   weightedMedian.hs:71:0-39: findVal :: [ValPair] -> Double -> Double
>   weightedMedian.hs:68:0-36: findVal :: [ValPair] -> Int -> Double

My solution is to have findValI and findValD. However, findValI just converts the Int type to a Double and calls findValD.

Also I can't pattern match on types of Num (Int, Double) so I can't just change the type signature to

```
findVal :: [ValPair] -> Num -> Double
```

In many languages I wouldn't need different names. Why do I need different names in Haskell? Would this be hard to add to the language? Or are there dragons there?

Comment: Try removing the function signature, loading it up in GHCI and type `:t findVal` to see the automatically computed function signature. It would probably not have either Int or Double, but instead look something like `Num a => [ValPair] -> a -> Double`, which is exactly what you need.

Comment: @Anupam Jain: Actually it the "real" version is [ValPair] -> Double -> Double. I could use Augustss' technique to get around that and then I do end up with the signature you list.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Ad-hoc polymorphism (and name overloading) are provided in Haskell by typeclasses:

```
class CanFindVal a where
          findVal :: [ValPair] -> a -> Double

instance CanFindVal Double where
     findVal xs d = ...

instance CanFindVal Int where
     findVal xs d = findVal xs (fromIntegral d :: Double)
```

Note that in this case, since `findVal` "really" needs a `Double`, I'd just always have it take a double, and when I needed to pass it an int, just use `fromIntegral` at the call site. You generally want typeclasses when there's actually different behavior or logic involved, rather than promiscuously.

Comment: Sure, it works, but not an idiomatic solution in this case. `CanFindVal` is not a terribly meaningful typeclass. -1

Comment: which sclv kind of said: "You generally want typeclasses when there's actually different behavior or logic involved, rather than promiscuously."

Comment: Thanks... I guess I'm used to the promiscuous nature of C++ overloading. As Luqui points out, I could probably do away with this issue.

Comment: I know this is almost a decade later, but I have heard the typeclasses are implemented as dictionary lookups. Couldn't it be done at compile-time?

Comment: @xilpex you'd think so, but as i recall, certain cases (e.g. polymorphic recursion), mean that you're not in a position to statically resolve every instance, even with whole-program compilation. There's no "no-go" proof I'm aware of, but every attempt I know of to do so has foundered. If typeclasses are made somewhat less general and powerful though, then, yes :-)

Answer (score 19):

Supporting both `findVal :: [ValPair] -> Double -> Double` and `findVal :: [ValPair] -> Int -> Double` requires ad-hoc polymorphism (see http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Ad-hoc_polymorphism) which is generally dangerous.  The reason is that ad-hoc polymorphism allows for changing semantics with the same syntax.

Haskell prefers what is called parametric polymorphism.  You see this all the time with type signatures, where you have a type variable.

Haskell supports a safer version of ad-hoc polymorphism via type classes.

You have three options.

1. Continue what you are doing with an explicit function name.  This is reasonable, it is even used by some c libraries, for example opengl.
2. Use a custom type class.  This is probably the best way, but is heavy and requires a fair amount of code (by haskells very compact standards).  Look at sclv's answer for code.
3. Try using an existing type class and (if you use GHC) get the performance with specializations.

Like this:

```
findVal :: Num a => [ValPair] -> a -> Double
{-# SPECIALISE findVal :: [ValPair] -> Int -> Double #-}
{-# SPECIALISE findVal :: [ValPair] -> Double -> Double #-}
findVal = ...
```

Comment: I'll check into specialization. It seems like sneaking in the back door but I'll take it.

Comment: does it require some extension to be enabled? I'm keep getting "multiple declarations" errors no matter if going with specialization or not

Answer (score 8):

Haskell does not support C++-style overloading (well it sortof does with typeclasses, but we don't use them in the same way).  And yeah there are some dragons associated to adding it, mostly having to do with type inference (becomes exponential time or undecidable or something like that).  However, seeing "convenience" code like this is pretty uncommon in Haskell.  Which one is it, an `Int` or a `Double`?  Since your `Int` method delegates to the `Double` method, my guess is that `Double` is the "correct" one.  Just use that one.  Because of literal overloading, you can still call it as:

```
findVal whatever 42
```

And the `42` will be treated as a `Double`.  The only case where this breaks is if you got something that is *fundamentally* an `Int`  somewhere and you need need to pass it as this argument.   Then use `fromIntegral`.  But if you strive to have your code use the "correct" type everywhere, this case will be uncommon (and when you do have to convert, it will be worth drawing attention to that).

Comment: Your question "which one is it, an Int or a Double?" is pretty much spot on. I was asked to write a "weighted median" function much like a weighted average function which takes a bunch of weights and values and calculates, in this case, the "weighted" median. Which is just fine if your weights are only natural numbers. However, we have fractional weights and I was to "approximate" the median. Which is mathematically somewhat meaningless but useful in the context of the project. So, yes, it should be an Int or Integer but I'm using Doubles for the weights. This has made my head hurt!

Answer (score 3):

In this case, I think it's easy to write a function that handles both Int and Double for the second argument.  Just write `findVal` so that is calls `realToFrac` on the second argument.  That will convert the `Int` to a `Double` and just leave a `Double` alone.  Then let the compiler deduce the type for you, if you are lazy.

Comment: realToFrac definitely fixes this problem. I think the bigger problem is that I was thinking like a C++ programmer.....

Comment: @Tim Perry Sometimes it would be nice if Haskell had the C++ kind of overloading, but often there's a nice way around it.

Comment: @augustss By sometimes do you mean "whenever NP-complete type inference sounds just downright exciting"?

Answer (score 2):

In many other programming languages you can declare (sort of) functions having the same name but different other things in their signatures, such as different parameter types. That is called *overloading* and certainly is the most popular way to achieve ad-hoc polymorphism.

Haskell deliberately does NOT support overloading because it's designers don't consider it as the best way to achieve ad-hoc polymorphism. The Haskell way rather is constrained polymorphism and it involves declaring type classes and class instances