# Can I pattern match on type name?

Tags: haskell

Is it possible to pattern match on the type name itself instead of on one of a type's constructors?

Here's a contrived example with code that doesn't compile which I hope explains what I'm after:

```haskell
what :: a -> String
what (x :: String) = "It's a String!"
what (x :: Int) = "It's an Int!"
what x = "Not sure what it is."
```

Comment: Mind that Haskell is in general statically typed, so the compiler needs to know the type in advance. You can however *overload* a function using typeclasses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

here is a version using type-classes:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances, FlexibleInstances  #-}
module Test where

class What a where
  what :: a -> String

instance What String where
  what _ = "It's a String!"

instance What Int where
  what _ = "It's an Int"
```

example:

```
λ> what "hi"
"It's a String!"
λ> what (1 :: Int)
"It's an Int"
```

and if you want the *else* case:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances, FlexibleInstances, OverlappingInstances  #-}
module Test where

class What a where
  what :: a -> String

instance What String where
  what _ = "It's a String!"

instance What Int where
  what _ = "It's an Int"

instance What a where
  what _ = "not sure"
```

example:

```
λ> what "hi"
"It's a String!"
λ> what (1 :: Int)
"It's an Int"
λ> what True
"not sure"
```

Comment: I get why you need `TypeSynonymInstances` (`String ~ [Char]`) and why you need `OverlappingInstances` in the last one (`What a` overlaps with the one for `Int` and the one for `String`) but why do you need the `FlexibleInstances` extension for?

Comment: you need it for the `String` too (says my GHC)

Comment: aah I think because you could define one for `[Int]` and one for `[Char]`

Comment: @epsilonhalbe if I get the technicalities right then it's because `[Char] ~ [] Char` is not allowed as it must be `[] a` with out `FlexibleInstances` ("All instance types must be of the form (T a1 ... an)
       where a1 ... an are *distinct type variables*")

Answer (score 5):

## Warning

Notice you are asking for something starkly non-idiomatic.  Whatever you are actually trying to do, this is probably not the right way to do it!

## Solution

Your top level type signature says you can handle any type what-so-ever and that just isn't going to fly.  Types are all lost at compile time so you need something to inform the code what the type was, something to make your branching decision.

There are a few lesser-used classes you could lean on here.  One is called `Typeable`, a class for types that have a run-time representation:

```
class Typeable (a :: k) where
  Data.Typeable.Internal.typeRep# :: GHC.Prim.Proxy# a -> TypeRep
```

In order to use typeable in your case you add the constraint to your type variable and use `typeOf` to acquire type representations:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiWayIf #-}
import Data.Typeable

what :: Typeable a => a -> String
what x =
    let ty = typeOf x
    in if | ty == intTy -> "It's an Int!"
          | ty == strTy -> "It's a String!"
          | otherwise -> "Something else, namely: " ++ show ty
  where
  strTy = typeOf ""
  intTy = typeOf (0 :: Int)
```

Yielding operation of:

```
*Main> what (1::Int)
"It's an Int!"
*Main> what "foo"
"It's a String!"
*Main> what 1.1
"Something else, namely: Double"
```

Comment: Yea, I wasn't going for something so non-idiomatic. I just wondered if there was some syntax I was missing. Thanks for the info on `Data.Typeable` though!

Answer (score 4):

No, that's not possible.

The only way to do different things depending on the type is to use typeclass methods that are implemented differently for each type.

Answer (score 3):

In a way you're trying to overload a function in Haskell. Have a look at this post that explains a method involving typeclasses which does that: [Overloading function signatures haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6119225/overloading-function-signatures-haskell)